# Including a URL with query string in an XML document

Tags: xml, encoding

So I have this XML doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Item>
        <URL>http://www.mysite.com/page?id=1</URL>
    </Item>
</Root>
```

When I try and view the document, I get an error saying:

> **XML Parsing Error: not well-formed**

at the `=` sign in the query string. I tried changing the `=` sign to `%3D`, but I get the same error at `%`

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Whatever XML parses claims that is isn't well formed, it's broken, because it is well formed. Try any online validator and they will all say the same thing "Well formed, no errors"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try `<URL><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/page?id=1]]></URL>`

All text in an XML document will be parsed by the parser.
But text inside a `CDATA` section will be ignored by the parser. You can find more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

Answer (score 22):

As you provide it, the XML is well formed. 
You don't have anything to escape in it. Maybe you have encoding problems in your source file.
For information, the 2 characters you must escape in XML are :

```
& in &amp;
< in &lt;
```

Characters you may escape in attributes values (depending on the syntax you use for attributes : `attr='value'` or `attr="value"`) :

```
" in &quot;
' in &apos;
```

Depending on the context, the last character that can be escaped :

```
> in &gt;
```

Comment: Why should CDATA be avoided?

Comment: @Adam: CDATA sections have drawbacks for several use cases such as nesting CDATA into CDATA (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting)). That means that if you want to insert, for example, arbitrary XML in a CDATA section (I already encountered people who tried that), implementation is not straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

try this `<URL><![CDATA[http://www.mysite.com/page?id=1]]></URL>`