# handling special characters (&, <, >) in xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, special-characters, xslt-2.0

Can anyone suggest, that while transforming from `xml` to `xml` in `xslt` if we do not want to use `cdata` in another `xml` how can we handle some special characters such as `&, > ,<` ?

It is not being transformed due to these special characters.

Comment: If your input is well-formed XML, then the XSLT processor can handle it. That means you need to escape any `<` or `&` that are not markup as `&lt;` and `&amp;` in your input and in your XSLT.

Comment: okay. i will try and let you know if it worked or not. Thanks . :)

Comment: You can have a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8215807/780733) for escaped characters in XML

Comment: Even if i do disable output escaping for these characters , nothing changes in the xml. it still shows the same error. I can replace the & character with and if i want, but what to do with the < character.

Comment: @user5440565 Your question is not clear. Please show us a small example of your XML input and the required output. In general, if your input is an XML document, the `&` and `<` characters will already be escaped or tagged as CDATA and you don't need to do anything.  Otherwise the input is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: We would find it a lot easier to tell you what you are doing wrong if you told us what you are doing.

Comment: Thnks everyone for the help. I solved it. :)

Comment: @user5440565 Please elaborate here, you may be helping others who read this question.